# Remove the header style css class in grid view asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

By using below code i am dynamically applying the css class for particular grid view header column.

```
gvMangeCareStaff.Columns[CurrentSortIndex].HeaderStyle.CssClass ="sort-asc"
```

But now i wanted to remove the class for this header column and don't wanted to apply any other class also. i was tried below code but it is not working.

```
gvMangeCareStaff.Columns[CurrentSortIndex].HeaderStyle.CssClass.Remove("sort-asc")
```

but it is not working. plz help me

Comment: When you execute the Remove code? you would need to bind GridView again.

Answer (score 0):

may this works
 Replace with empty string

```
gvMangeCareStaff.Columns[CurrentSortIndex].HeaderStyle.CssClass.Replace("sort-asc","");
```

Comment: i need in code behide file. like how i am applying the class for particular index  header column  in same way i need to remove that css class

Comment: I need to apply the class for only sorted column index  and remain all column i need to remove the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You Could try with this:

```
gvMangeCareStaff.Columns[CurrentSortIndex].HeaderStyle.CssClass.Replace("sort-asc","")
```